# Full text search in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have indexed the `ProductName` column in the `Product` table as full text search index. Some `ProductName` values as examples:

```
ProductName
-------------
Iphone 3GS
Iphone 4S
Iphone 5S
Iphone 5
```

Now I am using the following code to search for `Product`:

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"Iphone 4S"')
```

It's OK! But if I edit and use this:

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"4S Iphone"')
```

No results!

Could you help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 6):

you want find out results which contain Iphone,4S.So you can use OR condition to get the result.

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '4S  OR Iphone')
```

Following link will be more useful for better understanding.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'll want to use the [NEAR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142568(v=sql.100).aspx) between **4S** and **Iphone**. It searches for words with those, and the order can be independent.

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"4S" NEAR "Iphone"')
```

You can also use a tilde(~) in place of the NEAR statement

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"4S" ~ "Iphone"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Individual search-phrases should be encased in quotations.

If you were to compare the results of there 2 lines you would probably find the results you desire:

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"Iphone" and "4S"')

WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"4S" and "Iphone"')
```

This is because you might want to search on combinations which involve spaces:

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Product.ProductName, '"Sweet apple" or "Sour orange" or "Sour apple"')
```

In this case you would not be able to find a sweet orange for example.

The point is to not limit your search to individual words but actually allow you to require different combinations of words if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, nevertheless, wondering if

> FreeText

will address the issue of the OP, instead of using CONTAINS with AND/OR, as FreeText takes multiple keywords to search.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @fullTextCondition NVARCHAR(1000) = '4S Iphone'
 SET @fullTextCondition = '"' + REPLACE(@fullTextCondition, ' ', '" And "') + '*"'
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE CONTAINS(ProductName, @fullTextCondition);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered to be poor quality. Perhaps you can [edit] your answer and explain what the code does? Also, learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code.

Answer (score -5):

why dont you go with:

```
 product.ProductName like '%3GS%'
 product.ProductName like '%4S%'
```

if you want to be even more accurate then:

```
 where product.ProductName like '%4S%'
       and product.ProductName like '%Iphone%'
```

Comment: A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.

Comment: Although Mehmood's comment should a be a major concern using LIKE against millions of rows, indexing the target column and preventing user from using % at the very begining of the search expression should be an option. What I mean is that SearchExpr% is index friendly and that %SearchExpr% is not, therefore, not optimizable by the query engine.